# Building the Android Eclipse ADT from source

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

Since the Android source code is open, I want to build the  [ADT 11.0.0](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-11.0.0.zip) from source using Eclipse SDK. Is there any instruction to build the [code from source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/sdk.git;a=tree;f=eclipse/plugins;hb=HEAD) ?

Answer (score 3):

http://s.android.com/ is the website for people looking to build the Android development tools  from source.

Setup is described here: http://s.android.com/source/initializing.html

once you've setup your build environment with the right libs and downloaded the source (http://s.android.com/source/downloading.html) you can do the following on the command line in the directory you downloaded the code to:

```
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch sdk-eng
make sdk
```

This will make an SDK package including the ADT plugin in the out/host// directory under your source directory.